# « Tu m'étonnes » signifiant l'« approbation franche » ?

Tags: sens, locutions, origine-ou-raison, fréquence-utilisation

Le Wiktionnaire présente une locution interjective conjuguée à la deuxième du singulier du verbe [étonner](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9tonner), [*tu m'étonnes*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tu_m%E2%80%99%C3%A9tonnes), « expression qui se dit pour une approbation franche », différemment de l'ironie (*— J’aimerais bien gagner au Loto… — Oui tu m’étonnes !*), et synonyme de *c'est clair* (Wiktionnaire) :

> — Oh là là c’était bien les grasses mat’.
>  — **Tu m’étonnes**. —
> (François Bégaudeau, *Entre les murs*, 2006)

Connaît-on ce sens, est-ce courant, fréquent, exclusif à un registre particulier, est-ce un emploi récent, dérivé du sens par ironie ou y a-t-il une autre explication et distingue-t-on les deux sens de la locution uniquement par le contexte ?

Answer (score 1):

Je ne perçois pas deux sens différents.

C'est pour moi toujours une antiphrase ironique.

***Tu m'étonnes*** signifie en fait ***tu ne m'étonnes pas du tout***.

On commence à entendre « [ouais,] [j'avoue](https://twitter.com/LeRobert_com/status/1284143098134704128) » avec un peu le même sens (approbation totale).

Comment: Je pensais être le seul à ne pas connaître ça. Finalement ça ressemble davantage à un méfait lexicographique. Je connais le sens par ironie avec surtout _étonnant_ ou avec le substantif _suprise_ (_quelle suprise, je suis vraiment supris_). Avec j'_avoue_, par ironie tu veux dire ? Dans tous les cas on est loin de quoi que ce soit de bien _franc_.

Comment: Pour *J'avoue !*, pas par ironie mais glissement de sens.

Comment: Mais où est l'approbation franche dans tout ça ? Finalement je devrais peut-être poser une question là-dessus, je ne comprends pas. Comment un truc dit par ironie peut être aussi franc que _c'est clair_ ?

Comment: C'est peut-être l'adjectif *franche* qui t'ennuie. Je le comprends dans le sens de *nette*, *totale* sans lien avec la *franchise*.

Comment: Je le perçois comme une intensité et aucun des trucs ne me semble atteindre ce niveau-là mais je vais y réfléchir. Le tout illustre un double problème. Je ne reconnais pas vraiment l'emploi en question. Et je ne comprends pas sa qualification. Il y a des trucs comme ça qui ne t'entrent pas dans la tête. Parfois ça prend du temps.